# Dagger2 insert graph

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm using  [googles Dagger code lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-dagger#7) as my guide and I'm trying to insert a Dagger graph into my MainActivity but I'm running into the following error when I try to compile my code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.daggerpractice.MyApplication
        at com.example.daggerpractice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:20)
```

app.build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

...

    def dagger_version = "2.27"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```

AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component
interface AppComponent {

    // Factory to create instances of the AppComponent
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        // With @BindsInstance, the Context passed in will be available in the graph
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

MyApplication

```
open class MyApplication: Application() {
    // Instance of the AppComponent that will be used by all the Activities in the project
    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        // Creates an instance of AppComponent using its Factory constructor
        // We pass the applicationContext that will be used as Context in the graph
        DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
    }
}

I'm not sure why this working on the code lab but not in my app.
```

MyViewModel, is a class to mock a ViewModel.

```
@Singleton
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor() {
    var score = 0
}
```

MainActivity

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        //DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)
        (application as MyApplication).appComponent.inject(this)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you add `MyApplication` to your app manifest?  `<application android:name=".MyApplication"...`

Comment: Thanks @IR42 that was the problem, I don't think the Codelab had mentioned that.

Comment: You should be using Hilt. There are tutorials in the end of the page: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android